# How EntityManager works inside EJB 3.0 context, but not outside EJB context

Tags: hibernate, reflection, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

- So i have one EJB `EjbA` and a hibernate entity named `EntityA`.
- `EnitityA` has property `EnitityB` and some `String` type properties.
- `EjbA` has method `methodA` which manipulate `EnitityA`.

Now if i call a `methodA` of `EjbA`, the manipulate done on `EnitityA` will be reflected in db after the EJB call gets finish.

I know that when we call EJB method we actually call a proxy implementation on it which first start the db transaction, open hibernate session....

**But**

How does it call `hibernate.update` on the `EntityA` that has been changed in the method call ? basically how does ejb container knows that only entityA has been  modified in this EJB method call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load an entity with find() or some other query it gets into Managed state. It is bound with particular session and when the session is being closed/flushed entities bound with it are getting updated (therefore all modifications will be propagated into DB). And updating of HasA relationships (entityB within entityA) of the entities being updated depends on the cascade settings.

Comment: where did you find this info... a reference to some documentation will be great..

Comment: http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/1.2.x/manual/jpa_overview_em_lifecycle.html ... over here is pretty great explanation of how does the entity change its state depending on what method was called. Could be a good starting point for you.